# Creating smaller menus from chunks of a bigger menu

Tags: 7, routes

I have this really big nav menu in Drupal 7. The top-level links go to child pages. Each of these child pages has several pages hierarchically under them.

On these child pages, I want a block that shows links to sibling pages and children of the current page (But not children of sibling pages).

It seems like it should be relatively easy, but I've been beating my head against a wall all afternoon. Any help? Thanks!

Comment: Have you come across [Menu Block](http://drupal.org/project/menu_block/) before? If I understand you right it does exactly what you're after

Comment: That's cool, I wasn't sure if it was what you wanted (hence the comment). Mikey had enough courage in his convictions to actually put it as an answer so I'd go ahead and accept that one :)

Comment: Okiedokie then. Upvoted both of yours comments so you at least get some rep out of it. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are describing is the primary feature provided by the [Menu block](http://drupal.org/project/menu_block) module.